# Is there a way to configure a WinForms OpenFileDialog (or some other) to browse for website URL's instead of files?

Tags: c#, winforms, url, openfiledialog

The question says it all.

Is there a way to browse for website links such that, upon selection, it'll return the URL string from the dialog?

Answer (score 3):

You do not *browse* for website links since there is an almost infinite number (and how does your application know what they are?). Instead, you can just create a custom form with a textbox on it and sanitize the input (pass it to the [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) constructor which will parse it for you).

Answer (score 0):

As long as the ValidateNames property is false, you should be able to pull a URL out of the FileName property. You'll still have to deal with fetching the file specified in the URL on your own.